# jQuery sortable get .index() before and after sorting?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery's sortable on a tagging plugin,
The plugin maintains an array of objects that relate to the `li`'s in the same order as the actual items.

I need to update the order of the items in the array when the sorting finishes.

I thought I would just be able to in the start event call `$(ui).index()` and in the update event call the same which would give me the initial position, and the final position, but both calls return `-1`.

How should I do this?

---

**Structure:**

```
<ul>
<li>here<a class="close">x</a></li>
<li>are<a class="close">x</a></li>
<li>some<a class="close">x</a></li>
<li>tags<a class="close">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Array Structure:**

```
[{
    label: 'here',
    value: 36,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 0
},
{
    label: 'are',
    value: 42,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 1
},
{
    label: 'some',
    value: 21,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 2
},
{
    label: 'tags',
    value: 26,
    element: '$(the li that this info is about)',
    index: 3
}]
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui){...},
    update: function(event, ui){...}
});
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so we have someplace to start? It's difficult to guide you without knowing what ui is, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if  `.index()` is returning -1, that would suggest you are making that request prior to the element being available to the DOM. *or* you have mislabeled a selector and again it does not exist @ time of call or is empty in relation to the .index() function

Comment: You are correct, The issue was I needed to call `$(ui.item).index()` not just `$(ui).index()`!

Comment: Note: $(ui.item) is not necessary; ui.item.index() will work fine.

Answer (score 48):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) { 
            console.log('update: '+ui.item.index())
        },
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            console.log('start: ' + ui.item.index())
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: If you want the start index to be available to you in the update, then you'll need to set it like this:$(ui.item).data('startindex', ui.item.index()) and then access it with $(ui.item).data().startindex

Answer (score 4):

you can associate some data with each list item to keep track of them like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li data-id="1" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
<li data-id="2" class="ui-state-default">2</li>
<li data-id="3" class="ui-state-default">3</li>
</ul>
```

you can then access this data via jQuery like this:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(0)').data('id');
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').data('id');
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').data('id');
```